# A Lower bounds for exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find a "nonnegative" lower bounds for

$e^{uX-u^2Y} + e^{-uX-u^2Y} - 2 $?

where $u>0$, $Y \geq 0$ and $X \neq0$

I know I can bound above function by using the fact that $e^{uX} + e^{-uX} > 2$; i.e.,

$ (e^{uX} + e^{-uX})e^{-u^2Y} - 2 > 2(e^{-u^2Y} -1) $ but this yields negative value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks to me like that expression can indeed become negative. Fix $u$ and $X$ and let $Y$ grow very large. The expression approaches $-2$. I would say your greatest lower bound is $-2$. You can see that this is the case because the expression cannot ever equal $-2$. If you set the expression equal to $-2$, you will get $e^{-u^2Y}\cosh uX = 0$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your great comment, but what if I allowed to tune $u$? Can I have any chance to make above expression to be nonnegative?

Comment: It can always be nonnegative for any $u>0$. Fix $u$ and $Y$, and let $X$ grow large. The expression increases without bound. Note that the expression you are dealing with can be rewritten as $\boxed{2e^{-u^2Y}\cosh uX - 2}$

Comment: Can the one who downvoted this answer please explain why?!